# React - binding `this` to an imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my React app, I have a handful of functions that I'd like to be able to access across a few similar components... however, I want to bind `this` to the shared functions so that they can do things like update the component state, etc... however, it seems that importing the functions and then trying to bind `this` in the 'typical' React manner does not work.

Here's an illustration of what I'd like to accomplish - in this case, clicking the rendered button would call the function from the imported shared function file and update the component state:

```
//shared_functions.js
const sharedFunctions = {
    testFunction = () => {
        this.setState({functionWasRun: true})
    }
}


//MyComponent.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import sharedFunctions from '../static/scripts/shared_functions.js';
let { testFunction } = sharedFunctions;

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.testFunction = this.testFunction.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            functionWasRun: false
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.testFunction}>Click</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Trying to run this code as is will return an error like:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

and I get what that's all about... but what I'd like to know is: is it possible to bind `this` to an ***imported*** function?

I'm starting to get a lot of similar-looking functions popping up throughout my app and I'd love to simplify things by abstracting them into a shared script, but I'm not sure how to achieve the typical `this` binding that's needed to achieve state-setting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following line is not trying to bind the imported `testFunction` but rather a method `testFunction` of `<MyComponent>`

To bind the imported function, refer to it directly, as follows:

```
this.testFunction = testFunction.bind(this);
// Notice how:      ^--- there is no longer a this here
```

---

> **NB:  You're example tries to use bind on an arrow function**    **You cannot bind a new context to an arrow function.  
>
> *The  `this` context of an arrow function will always be set to the location
>   were it is defined.*** 
> You can get around this by declaring
>   testFunction using a regular function declaration:
>
> ```
> const sharedFunctions = {
>     function testFunction(){
>         this.setState({functionWasRun: true})
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I used it in the following way:

In constructor:

```
this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
```

In the imported file (be careful, no arrow):

```
export const handleChange = function handleChange(event) 
{
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: object
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ToastTimeout from 'toastTimout'
ToastTimeout.bind(this)('message to popup')
```

I was able to get the context of this in a simple service with a setTimeout function that changed the variable on `this` context

sorry for the sudo code